# What optimization method does "survreg" use?

Tags: r, maximum-likelihood, survival, optimization

I have a simple question whose answer I couldn't find in the manual of the R package 'survival':

What optimization method does the command 'survreg()' employ to obtain the maximum likelihood estimators?

https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/survival/html/survreg.html

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it requires essentially a yes or no answer and is somewhat unclear.

Comment: @MichaelChernick Sorry but a yes or no is not an answer to my question. I need to know the optimization method. Unless, of course, the optimization method is called "YES" or "NO".

Comment: Sorry I should have said that it requires a name.  It is a survival analysis method similar to a Cox proportional hazards model.

Comment: @MichaelChernick Not quite, `survreg' fits a linear regression model with **non**-propotional hazards for most of the distributional options.

Comment: It is a survival analysis model.  I only said that it is similar to the Cox model and not that it uses it.

Comment: I think the relevant code is [here](https://github.com/cran/survival/blob/master/src/survreg6.c): so maybies Newton's method

Comment: @user2957945 Interesting find. I think you are right, judging from the comments on the C code. I could accept that as an answer.